# Is it possible to execute a method after sending a response back to the browser in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I'm trying to run an action after I send a response back to the client in Rails.  Is it possible to do this without background workers or creating new threads?

I looked into the after_filter callback, but it seems like this only lets you execute code before you render the view / response.

Thanks

Comment: Please update your post with a description of what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is not possible. You have to use threads or some kind of delayed job framework ([Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), etc.).

Long answer: you actually can use ActionController::Live to control the moment on which your response is 'flushed' to client.

Modified example from the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html):

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    begin
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
      100.times {
        response.stream.write "hello world\n"
        sleep 1
      }
    ensure
      response.stream.close
    end
    do_my_after_response_job
  end
end
```